# Kubernetes statefulset ends in completed state

Tags: kubernetes, statefulset

I'm running a k8s cluster on Google GKE where I have a statefulsets running Redis and ElasticSearch.
So every now and then the pods end up in a completed state and so they aren't running anymore and my services depending on it fail.
These pods will also never restart by themselves, a simple `kubectl delete pod x` will resolve the problem but I want my pods to heal by themselves.
I'm running the latest version available 1.6.4, I have no clue why they aren't pickup and restarted like any other regular pod. Maybe I'm missing something obvious.

edit: I've also notice the pod get a termination signal and shuts down properly so I'm wondering where that is coming from. I'm not manually shutting down and I experience the same with ElasticSearch

This is my statefulset resource declaration:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  serviceName: "redis"
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: redis:3.2-alpine
        ports:
          - name: redis-server
            containerPort: 6379
        volumeMounts:
        - name: redis-storage
          mountPath: /data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: redis-storage
      annotations:
        volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class: anything
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
```

Comment: Can you check the attribute of restartPolicy: Always of this statefulset? The default value is always but want to make sure...

Comment: Yes I've checked the restart policy is `Always`

Answer (score 1):

> Check the version of docker you run, and whether the docker daemon was restarted during that time.
>
> If the docker daemon was restarted, all the container would be terminated (unless you use the new "live restore" feature in 1.12). In *some* docker versions, docker may incorrectly reports "exit code 0" for all containers terminated in this situation. See https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/31262 for more details.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43051371/5331893

Answer (score -1):

I am using same configuration as you but removing the annotation in the `volumeClaimTemplates` since I am trying this on minikube:

```
$ cat sc.yaml 
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  serviceName: "redis"
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: redis:3.2-alpine
        ports:
          - name: redis-server
            containerPort: 6379
        volumeMounts:
        - name: redis-storage
          mountPath: /data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: redis-storage
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
```

Now trying to simulate the case where `redis` fails, so execing into the pod and killing the redis server process:

```
$ k exec -it redis-0 sh
/data # kill 1
/data # $
```

See that immediately after the process dies I can see that the `STATUS` has changed to `Completed`:

```
$ k get pods                                                                                                                  
NAME      READY     STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
redis-0   0/1       Completed   1          38s
```

It took some time for me to get the `redis` up and running:

```
$ k get pods
NAME      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
redis-0   1/1       Running   2          52s
```

But soon after that I could see it starting the pod, can you see the events triggered when this happened? Like was there a problem when re-attaching the volume to the pod?